# How set up retry config fetching in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-cloud

I have config server and application fetches configs from this server. 
I want to set up retry mechanism of fetching. If config server is unavailable application shall sent requests for 10 minutes.

In spring docs i found next configs

```
spring.cloud.config.uri=http://localhost:9090
spring.cloud.config.fail-fast=true
spring.cloud.config.retry.max-interval=10000
spring.cloud.config.retry.max-attempts=2000
```

But they change nothing. My app doesn't do retry requests it just fails with

```
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
```

(Config server is down in that moment)

What am i doing wrong? There is way solve my problem?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved my problem by adding next @Bean to context

```
@Bean
    public RetryOperationsInterceptor configServerRetryInterceptor(RetryProperties properties) {
        return RetryInterceptorBuilder
                .stateless()
                .backOffOptions(properties.getInitialInterval(),
                        properties.getMultiplier(),
                        properties.getMaxInterval())
                .maxAttempts(properties.getMaxAttempts()).build();
    }
```

Answer (score 8):

The answer is a combination of the first two answers:

- You need to set `spring.cloud.config.fail-fast=true`
- You also need to add `spring-retry` and `spring-boot-starter-aop` to your classpath.

See the documentation [here](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/multi/multi__spring_cloud_config_client.html#config-client-retry).

Answer (score 3):

based on the info in the question I think you are lacking the following dependencies from your class path:

```
        <!-- for auto retry -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.retry</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-retry</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- for auto retry -->
```

Answer (score 1):

You set `spring.cloud.config.fail-fast` to true. According to the docs this will halt your application with an exception and not retry connecting.

Source: https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/multi/multi__spring_cloud_config_client.html#config-client-fail-fast